# How does NIC driver handle flow control?

Tags: networking, drivers, network-adapter

Using ethtool to query my driver for statistics with ethtool -S , I can confirm flow control is being used. I am receiving pause frames.

When using wireshark to sniff packets and then utilizing it's statistics tool to monitor udp traffic, I do not see any difference in the bps rate of my udp traffic whether flow control is on or off.

**What would be the reason for my host not throttling back it's traffic? How do I know if I am actually responding to the pause requests?**

Comment: What's the data rate of your source? Unless it's very high or your receiver is relatively slow by today's standards, the host OS shouldn't have a requirement to send PAUSE frames. A modern desktop machine can choke down well over a gigabit without heroic measures.

Comment: I have two hosts connected to a switch. One host sends at 10 GbE and the other host can't keep up. It sends pause frames to the switch and the switch sends pause frames to the host. I want the host(10 GbE) to throttle back its traffic.

Comment: Its ethernets job to do "fasts possible" so the 10G device will saturate the 1G(or 10/100) devices link. If you dont want this to occur you should be implementing it at the application layer.

Comment: @Linef4ult that is not what I am asking for help on. I want to understand why the NIC won't respond to pause requests.